# Microsoft Outlook 2003 Search Tools

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2003

Does anyone know of any free add-ons for Microsoft Outlook 2003 or later that will allow you to search email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lookout](http://www.majorgeeks.com/Lookout_d4808.html) which MS bought for some purpose is still available at Major Geeks. It was a great tool. Probably won't work for anything later than 2003 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I really like **Advanced Find** ... select the *Inbox*, press *CTRL+SHIFT+F*, then choose *Browse ...* then check *Select subfolders*.